# How to choose small and large class in Zurb Foundation?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation for Responsive Layout.
In this they are using like below example

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">...</div>
  <div class="small-4 large-4 columns">...</div>
  <div class="small-6 large-4 columns">...</div>
</div>
```

i don't know when will use small and when will use large class.Please explain those things.

Answer (score 2):

Classes starting with `small-` are used when browser window width is under 768px, when it's equal or over 768px `large-` classes will be used. There's also [Medium Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#medium-grid) but it's marked as an experimental feature (and therefore is not included by default).